# Does Google Chrome protect against cross site scripting (XSS)?

Tags: web-browser, xss, chrome

In Firefox I've been using the [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) extension to protect myself from certain kinds of malware attacks. NoScript is well known as a very powerful extension for Firefox and introduced protection from **XSS** and **clickjacking** attacks as far back as '07.

I've been looking for similar protection in Chrome, but the best I found was [ScriptNo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf) which does not specifically mention such a kind of protection (it only mentions Cross-Domain XML).

Does Google Chrome protect against cross site scripting (XSS)? (e.g. Is this passively achieved via sandboxing?)

Answer (score 13):

Chrome has default protection against Reflective XSS attacks.  This is not a flaw that sandboxing can address.  This protection system works by looking outgoing requests for javascript and preventing that javascript from being executed in the http response.  No browser will prevent DOM Based XSS or Stored XSS.

Chrome's protection is the weakest when compared to the others. [IE's xss filter isn't very good](http://www.exploit-db.com/wp-content/themes/exploit/docs/17875.pdf),  but slightly better than Chrome's.  From my research I think the NoScript is by far the best.  I have [bypassed NoScript's XSS filter](https://sitewat.ch/en/Advisories/27) by exploiting content insensitivity,  and they fixed the issue quickly.  Chrome and IE still suffer from content insensitivity attacks.

Microsoft says that content insensitivity attacks against IE are "not a vulnerability" and they will **never** fix these issues.  Chrome has had a bug report open for this issue and I haven't seen activity for about 6 months.  So chrome might fix it eventually, *maybe*.  Which to be honest both of these are horrible vendor responses.  In general I find that NoScript and Mozilla have the strongest responses to vulnerabilities in their software and **as a security researcher they are a joy to work with!**

Comment: Thanks for your informative input! Why do you think that even the Chrome team responds so slowly here? Is it because the focus is on protecting the computer and not the user information that is handled on a website? E.g. I could follow the IE statement "not a vulnerability" by saying that the fix should be provided by the website administrator. Still, I understand that this statement shows carelessness.

Comment: @gentmatt I'm not sure to be honest.  I think the chrome team has a lot on their hands and they are more concerned with just having a feature that says "protects against reflective xss" instead of making a really solid security feature.  Microsoft on the other hand is just notorious for leaving vulnerabilities unpatched.  A good example is the IE "drag-and-drop" vulnerability which was a remote code execution vulnerability left unpatched for almost two years.  I hate IE so much.

Comment: I would say it's because there is no way to make a 'perfect' XSS filter. There will always be ways to sneak content past a client-side filter that will cause a buggy server-side application to fail. The problem's in the server not the client, so you can't fix it there; the client-side XSS filter is a defence in depth measure that can't ever be watertight. By "fixing" it you would necessarily be adding to its false positives.

Comment: Personally I consider client-side XSS filtering to be a deeply mistaken idea, that only ever worked, for NoScript users, through obscurity: as long as there weren't too many users with NoScript, it could target the most common attacks and have some success. As soon as you build the filtering into a popular browser (ie: IE), it loses its effectiveness, as the attacks work around the filter.

Comment: @bobince  I think that they are effective to some extent,  and they aren't going away.  You should try exploiting an XSS flaw with a browser that has a filter, it is not trivial.

Comment: @bobince "_for NoScript users, through obscurity_" isn't NoScript free? do you mean "minority"?

Comment: @curiousguy he means that because the NoScript userbase is so small, it's obscure enough that attackers don't bother working around it's protections.  Same reason Mac's *used* to be secure: because the userbase isn't big enough to be worth targeting.

Comment: XSS prevention in browser is a potentially very dangerous feature if it blocks specifics scripts classified as XSS, if these scripts have security sensitive functions.

Comment: The link for "IE's xss filter isn't very good" is now broken, and the Internet archive doesn't have a copy of that web page.  Do you know of an updated link?

Comment: @D.W.  updated the link

Comment: Nowadays, _Chrome_ and _Firefox_ browsers prevent DOM Based XSS.

Comment: @Iratzar Carrasson Bores Incorrect, they prevent reflective XSS.  Identification of DOM-Based XSS cannot be automated - it is very difficult to identify because it can happen in so many different ways.

Comment: It can be, but for example in PentesterLab enviroment to exploit XSS, I done Reflective XSS atacks with Firefox but I couldn't exploit DOM-Based XSS.

Comment: @Iratzar Carrasson Bores try doing a js eval(), or document.write() with input from the request.  It works, and it is very expensive to prevent because you would have to  do taint/sink analysis at runtime.

Comment: It can be, but if you want use # to get a input value from user, it doesn't work in _Chrome_ and _Firefox_

Comment: @user10356 Chrome is slow to fix, speculatively, because Google's APIs depend on cross origin scripting. In fact, in the API ToS they forbid you from caching a version and serving the js from your own domain to your own app site.