# Reflected XSS Prevention plugin

Tags: web-browser, javascript, browser-extensions

Is there any plugin out there which prevent reflected XSS? Plugin could be either for firefox or chrome.

Thanks.

Comment: no-script for firefox,  none of these filers work very well.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome ( and most likely Firefox ) already prevent execution of scripts when they are given in for example the URL parameter, maybe even other things like a request body, and then proceed to give you a warning.

See also [Does Google Chrome protect against cross site scripting (XSS)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16247/does-google-chrome-protect-against-cross-site-scripting-xss)

Also when you search for XSS prevention in the chrome extension store, you will get results.

Comment: I tried a reflected XSS on insecurelabs.org/Task/Rule1. It works in chrome as well as firefox. here search box in vulnerable to xss

Comment: That website sends an http header of "X-XSS-Protection:0", you can guess what that does. You cannot use that website to test a browser's XSS Protection. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016960/google-chromes-xss-auditor-causing-issues)

Comment: Nice. But now I am making a simple page and running it on apache local server, still reflected xss happening

Comment: What would you say about http://victim.kotowicz.net/alphabet-hero/vuln.html

Comment: That is a page where javascript reads the input field and just appends the text as html, the xss data does not come from a request...