# How to bypass server side XSS filter for characters like < > / *

Tags: xss, reflected-xss

i was trying to exploit a website using XSS, but whenever I try an injection containing `<`, `>`, `/` or `*` I get the following message:

[image: Server Error in '/' Application]

I think website is trying to protect against XSS commands using something like a plugin or a code or a services. I want to know how to bypass this to do XSS.

Comment: Add ?bypassFilters=true to the URL and you should be good to go......

Comment: Voted to close this as it seems to be breaking/bypassing a security system which we will not help you with.

Comment: I have permission to do so

Comment: Still, it would be good to not get text in pictures. Or at least crop them to remove irrelevant parts.

Comment: related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183755/bypassing-xss-filter

Answer (score 1):

What you are encountering is the [IIS Request Validation protection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/request-validation). By the looks of it, you have not actually found an XXS/HTML-injection vulnerability, but are only hammering the Request Validation protection that blocks your *potentially bad requests*.

Reflected XXS is hard to exploit, because of the different protection mechanisms in browser and in your case, also on the server side. See this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16247/does-google-chrome-protect-against-cross-site-scripting-xss) for chrome XXS protection.

So in order for you to probe if this server actually have reflected HTML-injection vulnerabilities, you have to either ask the administrator to disable request-validation, or try to use innocent data in your payloads.

If I recall correctly, IIS Request Validator allow you to try less harmful HTML tags. I do not remember what works, but you have to experiment. If that string is reflected, it is a good chance that the underlying application is vulnerable, but still hard to exploit due to the protections on web-server and web-browser.

In your particular case, you are sending characters that are blacklisted in the path segment of the URI.

Comment: i had scanned the site using zap in kali and that show me that the site is using some kind of mechanism for protection against xss .

Comment: Yes, it is called Request Validator, which is provided by IIS web server